# What is the relevance of the DynamicTableEntity class?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

- I am migrating from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table` in [the (now obsolete) `WindowsAzure.Storage`](https://WindowsAzure.Storage) NuGet package to [`Azure.Data.Tables`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables) and I can see that there are places where `DynamicTableEntity` is being used in my project.
- But `DynamicTableEntity` is not present in the `Azure.Data.Tables` NuGet package, only `TableEntity` and `ITableEntity`.

  - `TableEntity` is available in:

    - [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://WindowsAzure.Storage) at `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity`
    - [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.dynamictableentity) at `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableEntity`
    - [Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/) at `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table.TableEntity`.
    - [Azure.Data.Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables) at `Azure.Data.Tables.TableEntity`.
  - `DynamicTableEntity` is available in:

    - [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://WindowsAzure.Storage) at `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity`
    - [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.dynamictableentity) at `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity`
    - [Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/) at `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table.DynamicTableEntity`.
    - But not in the [Azure.Data.Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables) NuGet package.

---

- Is there a difference between `TableEntity` and `DynamicTableEntity`?
- I read articles but still don't understand the relevance: `Azure.Data.Tables` v12 doesn't have a class `DynamicTableEntity` under `Azure.Data.Tables`.
- Is there any equivalent class that I can use for the same for the migration?

Comment: FYI, the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` library has been deprecated: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table/2.0.0-preview

Comment: It would help if we could see examples of how your project is currently using `DynamicTableEntity` so we can advise migration steps.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue with my code.  While reading the Microsoft docs, I found this description of the `TableEntity` type.  The `Azure.Data.Tables` `TableEntity` class is:

> A generic dictionary-like ITableEntity type which defines an arbitrary set of properties on an entity as key-value pairs.

This appears to be the replacement for DynamicTableEntity.  Furthermore, it implements:

> ITableEntity, ICollection<KeyValuePair<String,Object>>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>, IDictionary<String,Object>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,Object>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>, IEnumerable, IEnumerable

Also, it has type conversion helper methods that can be used in place of the former `EntityProperty` helper methods.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableentity?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: It's not a direct replacement, correct.  Admittedly I have not completed my code migration, but it looks like it has the right corresponding structures to make the migration possible.

Comment: Sorry - I deleted my comment after I saw you're right: `DynamicTableEntity` _isn't_ present in `Azure.Data.Tables` - only in the older libraries: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`, `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table`, and `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`.

Comment: That said, I'm not convinced that `Azure.Data.Tables`'s `TableEntity` class is any kind of adequate replacement for `DynamicTableEntity` because it doesn't provide any way of getting/setting arbitrary properties except via the untyped `Object this[String key] { get; set; }` indexer property. I really don't see how this new `TableEntity` class is any kind of improvement over `DynamicTableEntity` given how untyped it is.

Comment: I have currently made the changes with TableEntity but still dont understand the use of DynamicTableEntity

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this later. Here is an example of property updates in the
Azure.Data.Table world.

```
        public async Task<bool> UpdateField<V>(string partitionKey, string rowKey, string fieldName, V entityProperty)
        {
            var dynamicEntity = new TableEntity
            {
                PartitionKey = partitionKey,
                RowKey = rowKey
            };
            dynamicEntity.Add(fieldName, entityProperty);
            var result = await TableClient.UpdateEntityAsync<TableEntity>(dynamicEntity, ETag.All, TableUpdateMode.Merge);
            if (result == null || result.IsError) return false;
            return true;
    }
```

Note the ETag.All, this will simply blanket update the specified field regardless. Explore other options if you need to check the version of the record you are updating etc. Also note, V used for generic value in this instance as it is a part of a generic class that uses T already.